# Apache to share a /mount where the web page is stored using the networked connection. This worked using xampp ugh. Now using ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.4, virtual-machines, cifs, fstab, ubuntu-20.04

So this page [Where to put the web pages in /var/www/ or /var/www/html/ in apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1012855/where-to-put-the-web-pages-in-var-www-or-var-www-html-in-apache) is similar to what I am asking.  The rules wont allow me to ask joining questions to expand on that discussion. There are several others about /mount and fstab that are a bit of this same line of question.  This is on a hyper-term vm using ubuntu server that loads from a nas also.
The nas is freenas and has a 6T raid 1 array, since I have had a few SSD drives fail rather quickly with out warning.

So I cleaned and this is the first run vhost-Errorlog:  I think something might present to someone in the know. This is one call for the index.html page.  Using file:/// the pages loads completely properly in firefox...?

So I tried to post the list of errors and was denied the ability.

I am not sure what I am reading here but each link does have a file that corresponds to it as the files do in fact exist so a 404 error if I am reading that does not make sense.  450 is there but i ran chown -r www-data:www-data on the folder and files...  But there are still broken images on the page when it is browsed, the log also show a 200... I am confused with the error log data,

The error.log is rather long but can be posted if needed.
I do see some bits of wordpress that I installed and tried to remove which do not exist as I was not impressed with it.  Not sure to what that might have done to apache if anything.

I was using a irc room and a users suggestion cause me to have to reinstall apache then was bullied by that same user when I Asked the room for another opinion.  In another room a user suggested here and did not bully me so I am trying to find a solution here.

This is a rather interesting issue.  Mostly working but I think this is a permissions issue maybe???  I did find a actual typo issue with some help that fixed much of the /mount issue.

https://pastebin.com/bDfE23gt the error logs

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having? Your post says virtually nothing about it.

Comment: I tried to post the error log vhost. the issue  is a html file works find via file:/// but if called by apache as http it show as broken image links    The error log shows codes i think but the folder is chown for www-data and each error actually exists in the folder.  So I am not sure where the error is just that the web page does not build properly using apache linux but it works in windows xampp???

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bDfE23gt the error logs that I have, I found a pastebin that I could use to post it since this site wont allow it as a comment.

Comment: That's way too much irrelevant detail, reset the `LogLevel` to something sane, like `warn` or at worst `info`.

Comment: The only 404's are for wordpress which you say you removed somewhat. 450's are the size of the 404 response. Image requests are OK, 200.  This does not mean the images can't be damaged (faulty ssd?). If not, share the apache config.

Comment: I removed DNSsec that fixed one problem where my ip was not being resolved to the domain name.  Now it looks like a share and permission issue.       The LOCAL server IP won't resolve the apache servers page it is handing out.  The first issue was a global DNS issues.

Comment: I was able to get some help the first issue was found using curl... Now the fqdn resolves to the public ip.  The issue still exists and I am thinking at this time it is permissions... I tried to hit the local ip and the page is showing broken links using apache (apache is flawed maybe) but if you pull the same page using file:/// the page opens properly.  The SSD that failed was replaced and now only runs the host OS that has the Virtual server that runs apache that mounts the nas4free share which is a CIFS share.

Comment: The shares are using nas4free across the network since the nas is a raid using shadow having 6T drives.   Funny this page loaded fine using xampp in this configuration. I think since locally it won't populate images using http it is a traverse issue....  Permissions.... The owner is root:root not www-data:www-data....  So I am investigating NFS for sharing that folder, but that is giving an unable to resolve 192.168.3.107 error???  So ubuntu can not resolve an IP?  again there is a functioning share using that ip.???

Comment: UGHHHH finally wacked on the keyboard and got it working.  The traverse across drives does not like a cifs share so that worked 50% but a NFS share works 100%.  seems that permissions are not set for the graphics, but now I have the nas sharing the web page so the server is now running 100% across a network from a raid 5 shadow drive.  I feel that I have some redundancy now unlike before when the SSD just stopped working 1 month after install and build-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UGHHHH finally wacked on the keyboard and got it working.  The traverse across drives does not like a cifs share so that worked 50% but the NFS share works 100%.  seems that permissions are not set for the graphics, but now I have the nas sharing the web page so the server is now running 100% across a network from a raid 5 shadow drive.  I feel that I have some redundancy now unlike before when the SSD just stopped working 1 month after install and build-out.
So installed the nfs common componets
edited fstab after mashing commands until I came up with the right combination
the issue was dealing with curl and dnssec being broken then pounding out a nfs share so that unix permissions could traverse.
restarted apache (probably was not needed) and refreshed the page and it all populated properly even the broken images.  So it was NOT corrupted images as I kept saying they were fine.
Just needed to find the right end to start working on.  Thanks to a MOD on freenode that helped me get dnssec fixed so that I could locate the rest of the issue.
The Loglevel had the error in it if you just read it right.